# How to manage objects?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development.
I want to know how you all manage objects.
For eg we make object as A a = new A(); and then manage that object.
But, here, we call A.class;

My concern is that i dont want to call onCreate(),nor do i want to push UI screen.
I just want to make 1 static object for 1 screen;and want to manage it throughout my application
that is, instead of calling A.class; can i call A a = new A(),and manage that object without pushing,and whenever i need i push that screen. Is there someway ?

Thanks...

Comment: Static class calls in Java is done by MyClass.MyStaticMethod(), MyClass.class is for reflection purposes.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to make 1 static object for 1 screen;and want to manage it throughout my application that is

That somehow describe what an Activity is for. Your complete question suggest that you have no idea how Android works and why it is meant to be. You should start at least with the fundamentals and than work through tutorials to get a feeling. Fundamentals can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html